# Unity3d model not loading clearly

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, normals

I am new to Unity. I am loading .dae model file in the Unity. My model has two parts. When I am seeing model from one side the one part is appearing and other not and when I am rotating the model the other part appears and the first one not.

I am not sure whether it is a normals problem or some other problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normals seem inverted indeed. In the inspector, when selecting the model in your `Project` folder, what parameter have you chosen for the normals ? "Import" or "Calculate" ? Also, check your normals in your 3D modelling software.

Comment: Thanks for reply  parameter for normal  is Import in unity3d

Comment: Have you tried to change it for "Calculate" ?

Comment: Yes i tried but result is still the same.Do you want my .dae file .

Comment: I'm not good enough in 3D modelling in order to help you more, I'm sorry. The suggestions I gave you was the only solutions which came to my mind.

Comment: No problem, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The issue with it is that the order of the vertices in every triangle is different from one side to the other.

[image: Normals and their correspondence with vertex rotation]

To fix this you should select one half of the model in your 3D modeling application and choose a function whose effect is to reverse the normals.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply can i send you my .dae file

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the required program to fix this